# Error adding bridging header into existing objective project

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have added bridging header into my existing objective c project and import objective c file into bridging header using #import "classname.h". but when I am compiling the code the error is coming in objective c class(Which I added in bridging header) asking to import uikit and foundation framework.
Or if I am adding another class which is having more dependencies on another classes, it is asking to import all the dependent framework/classes.

I tried adding/removing bridging header, delete derived data multiple times, but no luck.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

@objc is the possible keyword as I guess.
 Otherwise, Have you tried all the process in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/3426053.

I wish it could be a little help.